# $X \sim U[-1,1]$, is there $Y$ independent of $X$ s.t $X+Y$ and $\frac{Y}{2}$ have the same distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, characteristic-functions

I have thought that if there exist such $Y$ then we can look at characteristic functions of $X + Y$ and $\frac{Y}{2}$ to get:

$$  \phi_{X+Y}(t)= \phi_X(t)\phi_Y(t) = \phi_{\frac{Y}{2}}(t) \\ \frac{\exp(it) - \exp(-it)}{2it}  \phi_Y(t) = \phi_\frac{Y}{2}(t) \\
\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\phi_Y(t)=\phi_\frac{Y}{2}(t)$$

But I don't see how to proceed with this approach. Is there anything I could do with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show by induction that $\phi_Y(2^{-k}\pi) = 0$ for $k \in \mathbb{N_+}$ and from it follows that $\phi$ is not continous at $t = 0$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\text{Var}(X+Y) = \text{Var}(Y/2)$.  Simplify and use the fact that a variance must be nonnegative.

Comment: I see, that works. But I am still interested if i can get contradiction from characteristic functions.